# How to create a webservice returns json string only?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

I've set the web.config to let it support 'get' request.

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpSoap"/>
    <add name="Documentation" />
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Then,i want the webservice just returns json strings,not xml!but i've set

[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]

it not works,still returns strings with jsonstrings....

I don't want to set contentType in the page file,just use the default!